# Share getter/setter classes across asp.net applications

Tags: asp.net

Maybe there's something obvious that I'm missing or maybe not. Suppose I have a class that is just a representation with getters/setters and no logic. I'm going to use these structures for serialization/deserialization mostly. Suppose I use that object in many, many applications. Suppose I have dozens of these objects. What's my best approach to sharing these objects?

I understand that I can compile an object into a DLL and reference that DLL. But if I have dozens of these objects, do I compile them all separately so I can use just what I need or do I make and maintain a monster DLL with all of these objects in it. Both of those approaches seem bad. I don't want to create a class library for every single class (that's stupid) and throwing them into a giant package just seems like a bad idea.

Am I missing something simple? Doesn't java have a convention where one can create jar files of one to many classes? Does .Net do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a happy middle ground.

You should be grouping related objects into individual namespaces.

You can then compile each namespace into a seperate DLL. That way, whoever is using the libraries only needs to reference a single DLL per group of functionality.

Comment: I think this seems like the best answer. My only potential problem is that depending on abstraction, there might be objects that aren't easily logically grouped together. It does seem strange to me that there isn't a pattern in place to better address this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a master assembly containing all objects. Then also create separate assemblies for the different applications where you only add the ones you use as links.

You would then use Project->Add Existing Item, and then on the Add-button click the down-arrow and select "Add As Link" when you add the classes you want.